# Dealing with a co-worker with a farting problem

Tags: professionalism, work-environment

I have a co-worker who stands behind me at work, our desks face away from each other with a few feet between.

For the last month I have heard audible farts at least once per day, and several people sitting near me have smelled them 2-4 times per day.

Having a direct conversation could be awkward because he is not a peer, he is a manager. Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

edit: I think this is different from the hygiene question because the roles are reversed. I am not a manager of the person in question, they are the manager

Comment: What do you expect this person to do? Should they quit allowing their body to perform it's natural functions? It's 1 audible fart a day and maybe 2-4 quiet ones. Do you not pass gas?

Comment: We have a bathroom very close and a lot of open space for a quick walk. It has gotten to the point that 4 or 5 people are smelling it every few hours.

Comment: @TStauff, there is a little thing called professionalism and common courtesy in the workplace.  No one is saying he has to quite performing bodily functions, but it's really in bad taste to do it when you have co-workers that close, especially if you can help it.

Comment: Might be a medical issue. You may wish to approach HR about it - just be very very polite.

Comment: @TStauff Do you not leave the room to pass gas be it a work or social occasion?

Comment: Tell him to get a pet dog - usually a good cover and they do not mind getting the blame :->

Comment: What is wrong with telling him/her to go fart elsewhere? That seems reasonable to me. Politely of course.

Comment: Reminder: dometimes this really is a mefical condition, not under control. If you're going to raise the question, it's a lot safef to phrase it as an honest question,  "could you try to...", since the answer may legitimately be "I wish I could, but."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get user1220 may have been kidding about throwing a match but if the workplace allows candles a small candle is effective. Unfortunately a lot of workplaces will not allow candles. If anyone asks why the candle just say "control environmental odors".  If that person asks then tell him to "to control your odors".

Comment: Yes, that was the gist of it. A flame will burn off the gas.

Comment: @user1220: the flame doesn't burn the gas. Our nose is for historic reasons very sensitive for the smell if fire. This is the reason why you only smell the match after lighting it. Not burning away the gas.

Comment: @eckes Uh, methane (as many hydrocarbons) is flammable.

Comment: @Frisbee: correct. But methane doesn't smell :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane says `At room temperature and standard pressure, methane is a colorless, odorless gas.` But I didn't want to start nitpicking here. Lighting a match works. Doubtless.